# Multiple Variations for Products Database

Tags: mysql, database-design, e-commerce, database-schema, entity-attribute-value

I know there are lots of questions with same concern but i have gone through so many answers but unfortunately i didn't understand or may be not satisfied.

**Goal**
I want my products can have multiple attributes and based on their combination they can have their price , sku and stock

**Example**
T-shit product has size, color and material attributes (options)

so i want this flexible strucute that

> Color: Red, Size: M , Material: Soft -> price $1, sku XXX, stock 3
>   Color: Red, Size: L , Material: Soft -> price $2, sku XXX, stock 4
>   Color: Black, Size: XL , Material: hard -> price $3, sKu XXX, stock 4

Right now i have the following structure that is okay if only one attribute (option) is provided. But it does not fit for variations (combo).

**Products Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `long_description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `short_description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `images` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `discount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_start` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_end` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `released_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Options Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `options` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Products_Options Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `products_options` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `option_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `available_stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

So the `products_options` table can store products in the following way

```
Color: Red -> price $1, sku xxx, stock 3
Size: M -> price $1, sku xxx stock 3
```

But it does not reflect if i want to store color:red size:m having one price and sku and stock

Thanks

Comment: Search the EAV tag I added.

Comment: @Raheel I hope you have the solution. Can you provide the answer ?

Comment: @SankalpTambe I gave up using SQL

Comment: @RaheelKhan I hope you got the solution. Please provide the answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MitulKoradiya Sorry bro, I gave up that project. Should i delete this question or let it be like this so that someone else can benefit with answers below ?

Comment: Are u Got something?

Answer (score 0):

You should try putting the price, sku, and stock fields in your product table.  Each unique product has exactly one of these fields, and belong in the product table.  [Please look at the sample db schema.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y4gp.png)

Comment: This is not solving my problem bro. How can you query for example: Get all shirts that are Red color and are of Small size ?

Answer (score 0):

you will have split the products main info and other info (size/color) into 2 tables..

**Products** (name, description, etc) - this would be for products that all have the same specs -ie a certain range of socks for example.. its the "family" - it does not store any stock, treat it as an empty shell.. Important to note here you would differentiate say between Womens and Mens versions of a product and create a new product here for each..

**ProductsQty**: This would list the id of the product (above), and then have size/color columns with multiple rows for each variation - if you have say 3 (size,color,weight) you would need 3 rows for example.. (to go 1 step further for non clothes items) - this would be the primary "spec"of the product - ie Medium or large, or 330ml, 200w, basically what determines the basic size of the unit, be it ml,mm,inches,grams,watts,volts.. u can expand this - bearing in mind that the product type will determine where to split the two. Clothes have colors and size, but a fuel tank might have a liter as primary differentiation, and possibly a color too - so you could have a varchar column and enter whatever unit, gallons, feet, (im using matrix1, matrix2, matrix3 to be more generic..)

You would need a new row for each color **and** size.. blue socks in medium are a different product to blue socks in Small..

Major feature differences should be a new product - ie, if you have a speaker set thats similar to another model, but has say - additional bluetooth, this would be a new top level product.. you have to be smart when to split the size/color and when to create a new product. You store only color/size variations in the second table for your example..

Tie it up:

**Example product: Mens Sierra Dri Down Jacket **

**Products table** (id,name,description):

221, Mens Sierra DriDown All Weather Jacket, Great quality 3 season Jacket bla bla

**ProductsQty** (id,prodid,size,color,qty)

998, 221, Large, **Blue**, 22

999, 221, Large, **Black**, 4

If you have more than one store you would use the ProductsQty id in a new table and have the storeid and qty for each of the sub products there..

you can also store the sku in either table - if the family has the same sku store it in products, if not - put it in at the ProductsQty table..

Now you can search for either size / color / sku - hope this makes sense..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not solve my problem. I thought of this solution too, but what if there is a new attribute, e.g. model. You have to adjust the database table then, and I don't want that.